# Put dash between every third character

Tags: php, string, replace, substr

I had a problem on how to put dash in every 3rd character. For example, I want

```
ABCDEF turn into ABC-DEF
```

I have this code:

```
$string = 'ABCDEF';
echo substr_replace(chunk_split($string,3),'-','3','2');
// the output is ABC-DEF
```

However this code does not work if I add more characters to the $string variable such as `ABCDEFGHI`. If I use the above code, the output will be:

```
ABC-DEF GHI
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You should use PHP's [`str_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) and [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) functions.

```
function hyphenate($str) {
    return implode("-", str_split($str, 3));
}

echo hyphenate("ABCDEF");       // prints ABC-DEF
echo hyphenate("ABCDEFGHI");    // prints ABC-DEF-GHI
echo hyphenate("ABCDEFGHIJKL"); // prints ABC-DEF-GHI-JKL
```

See http://ideone.com/z7epZ for a working sample of this.

Answer (score 14):

Simply:

```
join('-', str_split($str, 3))
```

Answer (score 3):

Everyone failed to mention wordwrap:

```
echo wordwrap('ABCDEFGHI', 3, '-', true);
```

Answer (score 2):

## Example of Put dash between every third character

```
$string = 'ABCDEFABCDEF';
echo join('-', str_split($string, 4));
echo join('-', str_split($string, 2));
```